# How do you handle guard clauses and throwing exceptions when delegating method has the same guard?

Tags: java, oop

This question was intended to ask only about how to handle calling a method of an object that checks for the same condition as the calling method and throws the same exception type. Due to the nature of the problem it turned into a question about class design.

I'm experimenting with class designs for a chess program. I originally made a `Chessboard` class with methods that allow you to `put` pieces. The reasons being:

1. It's immutable and I figured repeatedly creating new board objects just to initialize it seemed unnecessary.
2. The board ideally should be populated once with the pieces, and further changes to the board should happen through the `Chessboard`'s interface.

I made a mutable `PieceSet` class that is passed in the `Chessboard` constructor.

```
// Showing as interface instead of class, because implementation is not important
public interface PieceSet
{   
    void putBishop(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void putKing(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void putKnight(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void putPawn(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void putQueen(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void putRook(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    void removePiece(Square square);

    void relocate(Square fromSquare, Square toSquare) throws UndefinedSquareException;
}
```

In the implementation of `PieceSet` the methods would use a guard to check for null squares

```
if(null == square)
    throw new UndefinedSquareException(...);
```

The `Chessboard` class would use the `PieceSet` class, for example, like this:

```
public final class Chessboard
{
    private PieceSet pieces;

    public Chessboard()
    {
        this.pieces = new PieceSet();
    }

    public Chessboard(PieceSet initialPieces)
    {
        this.pieces = new PieceSet(initialPieces);
    }

    public Chessboard removePiece(Square square) throws UndefinedSquareException
    {
        /*
         * Check for null here and throw exception??
         * PieceSet does the same thing.
         */

        PieceSet newPieces = new PieceSet(this.pieces);

        newPieces.removePiece(square);

        return new Chessboard(newPieces);
    }

    public Chessboard movePiece(Square fromSquare, Square toSquare)  throws UndefinedSquareException
    {
        /*
         * Check for null here and throw exception??
         * PieceSet does the same thing.
         */
        PieceSet newPieces = new PieceSet(this.pieces);

        newPieces.relocate(fromSquare, toSquare);

        return new Chessboard(newPieces);
    }
}
```

The question then is, since `Chessboard` also receives `Square` type parameters and they should not be `null`, do I also put the guard in `Chessboard`'s `removePiece` and `movePiece` methods?

```
if(null == square)
    throw new UndefinedSquareException(...);
```

## Another Idea

Another idea I had was to model the `PieceSet` as just a builder for a `Chessboard` (Although `PieceSet` might not be a good name anymore, I won't change the name for the example). I thought since the original idea of the `PieceSet` was to use it to create a populated `Chessboard`, then I would make it the `PieceSet`'s responsibility to do this instead of passing it to the `Chessboard`.

```
public interface PieceSet
{   
    putBishop(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    putKing(Square square, Color color) throws UndefinedSquareException;

    // Same from above, etc. EXCEPT no remove or relocate methods

    // This is new
    Chessboard createBoard();

}

// The Chessboard doesn't have to use PieceSet. It can be implemented using any data structure to store pieces.
public final class Chessboard
{
    private Map<Square, Piece>pieces;

    public Chessboard(Map<Square, Piece> initialPieces)
    {
        this.pieces = new HashMap<Square, Piece>(initialPieces);
    }

    public Chessboard removePiece(Square square)
    {
        // No more duplication of checking for null square, and throwing exception
    }

    public Chessboard movePiece(Square fromSquare, Square toSquare)
    {
        // No more duplication of checking for null square, and throwing exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I would probably not guard it and just let the underlying exception through; if you wanted to decorate the underlying exception I suppose that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In general, say we feel strongly that an interface should throw a checked exception. Further, we want to decorate a strategy object providing an implementation of that interface. Finally, we feel the checked exception from the interface is applicable to callers of the decorator. In this case, if the exception thrown by our delegate needs to be passed to callers of our decorator, then yes, you'd throw that same exception in your decorator.

But specific to the Chessboard problem: I'm not sure I agree that UndefinedSquareException should even be a checked exception. Why would a user of this API ever provide a reference to a null Square, or a Square not managed by this Chessboard, and expect to recover? As a result, I tend to think that UndefinedSquareException extends RuntimeException and doesn't need to be in your signatures at all, or that the Chessboard catches the checked exception from PieceSet and throws a RuntimeException in its place.

Hope this helps -- enjoyed reading your question and thinking about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If a function validating a condition which is also validated by it's callers, it's an indication that design needs improvement. Particularly having several null checks is a poor design. This can be avoided by a better arrangement of responsibilities and sometimes using [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

The design in the first example, seems to be unnecessarily complicated. PieceSet is mutable, but it's re-created every time it's changed. Why not making it immutable first place then?

Secondly responsibility of Chessboard is not clear. All the job is done by PieceSet. PieceSet knows where the pieces are, how to move them, how to remove them etc.. Chessboard is just a [Middle Man](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/remove-middle-man).

Due to this fact, actually Chessboard do not need to guard against null Squares. It's not using Squares at all, and would not recognize if a null square is passed.

Your second idea is easier to follow and less complex. PieceSet is only responsible of initial population of board, and will not cause continuous pollution within Chessboard. Chessboard is responsible of movements and removal of pieces. A clear separation of concerns.

Another suggestion would be using one function for placing pieces like

```
putPiece (Piece piece, Square square, Color color)
```

instead of having one function for each type of pieces. By this way you can centralize validation of placement like guarding against null Squares.

Comment: I like the second idea better also. My original design used a `putPiece(Piece, Square, Color)` method. `Piece`s are used to calculate moves. I changed it when I had the _brilliant_ idea that the set of pieces placed on the board is a closed set, and people may have drastically different ways of representing pieces and calculating moves for each piece, so instead of forcing clients to implement my interface I would let them write their own movement calculation in the implementation of `Chessboard`. Perhaps this was a step backwards? Maybe I should just write a sufficient `Piece` interface?